# Cannot start kibana-4.1.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

My environment

```
CentOS 6.6
elasticsearch-2.0.0-rc1.rpm
kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64

[root@node2 files]# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

I am new to ELK stack. I have installed Elasticsearch and did not change any settings. It seems to me there is no issue with Elastic search.

http://localhost:9200

Outputs

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                             
  "name" : "Danielle Moonstar",                                                                                                                                                               
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",                                                                                                                                                           
  "version" : {                                                                                                                                                                               
    "number" : "2.0.0-rc1",                                                                                                                                                                   
    "build_hash" : "4757962b01a4d837af282f90df9e1fbdb68b524e",                                                                                                                                
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-10-01T10:06:08Z",                                                                                                                                               
    "build_snapshot" : false,                                                                                                                                                                 
    "lucene_version" : "5.2.1"                                                                                                                                                                
  },                                                                                                                                                                                          
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Now, if I go to Kibana(did not change anything) and run it

```
 [root@node2 files]# /usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/bin/kibana
```

It gives following errors-

> {"name":"Kibana","hostname":"node2.mydomain.com","pid":2253,"level":50,"err":{"message":"unknown
>   error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: unknown error\n    at respond
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:237:15)\n
>   at checkRespForFailure
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n
>   at HttpConnector.
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n
>   at IncomingMessage.bound
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n    at
>   _stream_readable.js:944:16\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)"},"msg":"","time":"2015-10-15T09:41:15.952Z","v":0}
>   {"name":"Kibana","hostname":"node2.mydomain.com","pid":2253,"level":60,"err":{"message":"unknown
>   error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: unknown error\n    at respond
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:237:15)\n
>   at checkRespForFailure
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n
>   at HttpConnector.
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n
>   at IncomingMessage.bound
>   (/usr/local/kibana-4.1.2-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n    at
>   _stream_readable.js:944:16\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)"},"msg":"","time":"2015-10-15T09:41:15.952Z","v":0}

Not sure how to fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest trying out Kibana 4.2.0-beta. Elasticsearch 2.0 has many differences compared to 1.x.

Answer (score 4):

As Andrei Stefan suggested, Kibana 4.2.0-beta solved the issue. 
Wasted my whole day.