# Unable to start Kibana server

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed elastic search 2.3.5. and have Kibana 4.1.11 for windows.

I configured elastic search url in Kibana.yml

```
elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200"
```

When I ran kibana.bat file i'm getting the below error

[image: Error Message]

Any suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145382/cannot-start-kibana-4-1-2

Comment: error occurs due to compatibility issue.